# Strange issue : Set value to respective object's property

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, xcode6

This is my code for filter/convert NSDictionary to any respective class (model) object.

My Code is as below

```
-(NSMutableArray *)filterArray:(NSMutableArray *)arrList WithClass:(Class)class
{
    NSMutableArray *arrFilterArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:arrList.count];
    for(NSMutableDictionary *dicUser in arrList)
    {
        id classObject = [[class alloc] init];

        if([dicUser respondsToSelector:@selector(allKeys)])
        {
            for(NSString *key in dicUser.allKeys)
            {
                @try
                {
                    [classObject setValue:[dicUser valueForKey:key] forKey:key];
                }
                @catch(id anException)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Exception: %@",anException);

                    //do nothing, obviously it wasn't attached because an exception was thrown
                }
            }
            [arrFilterArray addObject:classObject];
        }else
        {
            return arrList;
        }
    }
    return arrFilterArray;
}
```

This code is working fine with xCode 5.1.1 and for xCode 6.0 to above, It's return Exception only where any dictionary's key value is Numeric.

Another strange i just got, Now, It's working fine with iPhone but not for iPad... This is really unbelievable..

Hope, I'll get solution here.

Comment: Try [NSNumber numberWithInt:1] for numeric value

Answer (score 0):

the problems is when you have a numeric value, this line:

```
 [classObject setValue:[dicUser valueForKey:key] forKey:key];
```

tries to put this value: [dicUser valueForKey:key] to a property of the classObject what its name is  key (a numeric value), and any class object can't have a property with name is a numeric value.

If in your dict you can receive some numeric values, your classObject should implement this method in order to deal with them:

```
-(void)setValue:(id)value forUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key
{
if ([key isEqualToString:@"123"])
{
    self.myPropertyFor123 = value;
}
else
{
    // To cacht others mistakes.
    [self valueForKey:key];
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, But i'm using this method in Category of NSObject. So, I can't get self. myPropertyFor123 for each class.

Comment: Sorry, where do you store the value ? In a Category you can't add a new property or instance variable.

Comment: Value should be stored in respective class object not in categories. And i'm not creating any property in category

Comment: @Sweeta sorry, do you override the NSObject methods (setValue:forUndefinedKey:) in a category ?. How ? Please let me see it.